# Using cmake to build SQLite3 from source is not working

Tags: c, sqlite, cmake

I am working on Linux Fedora 39. I am new to using cmake, and though a good first cmake exirsize would be to build sqlite3 from source.

I downloaded the sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h source files from the official sqlite site. I want to compile the source code to an .o (object) file, so it can be linked to my main application later on. Running cmake gives no errors and then running the make file it generated gives me no errors and says that the build completed, but when I go to look in my directory there is no sign of my .o file, or any compiled file for that matter.

I know that some of the methods used in the cmake file might not be required (like using globbing), but like I said, I am still playing around with cmake and seeing what will work for me and fit my future project requirements.

My cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

project(SQLite3
    VERSION 3.0
    DESCRIPTION "SQLite3 source code"
    LANGUAGES C)

# Specify your source directories
set(SOURCE_DIRS 
    "../source" )

# Initialize an empty list to hold all source files
set(SOURCES "")

# Set the output directory for object files
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")

# Use globbing to include source files from each directory
foreach(SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIRS})
    file(GLOB_RECURSE DIR_SOURCES 
        "${SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp"         
        "${SOURCE_DIR}/*.c" 
        "${SOURCE_DIR}/*.cxx")
    list(APPEND SOURCES ${DIR_SOURCES})
endforeach()

# Add the source files to the executable target
add_library(SQLite3 OBJECT ${SOURCES})

# ******I realise this might not be required for this case, but I tried it in any case**************
# Include the directory containing sqlite3.h if necessary
target_include_directories(SQLite3 PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../headers")

# Set compiler flags based on OS
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")
    # Add compile flags before compiling
    target_compile_options(SQLite3 PRIVATE 
        -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fPIC)
elseif (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
    # Add compile flags before compiling
    target_compile_options(SQLite3 PRIVATE 
        -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fPIC)
elseif (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Darwin")
    # Add compile flags before compiling
    target_compile_options(SQLite3 PRIVATE 
        -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fPIC)
endif()

# Set the version of the compiler
target_compile_features(SQLite3 PRIVATE c_std_11)
```

My file structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JowyN.png)

Note, when generating the below outputs, I made sure to delete all my generated cmake files and folders to ensure it is a fresh output, as if it is being run for the first time.

Cmake console outputs:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/build
```

Cmake MakeFile console outputs:

```
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/SQLite3.dir/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c.o
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c: In function ‘sqlite3VdbeExec’:
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:96200:50: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
96200 |                    zPayload[6] = (u8)(v&0xff); v >>= 8;
      |                                                ~~^~~~~
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:96201:11: note: here
96201 |           case 6:  zPayload[5] = (u8)(v&0xff); v >>= 8;
      |           ^~~~
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:96202:50: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
96202 |                    zPayload[4] = (u8)(v&0xff); v >>= 8;
      |                                                ~~^~~~~
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:96203:11: note: here
96203 |           case 4:  zPayload[3] = (u8)(v&0xff); v >>= 8;
      |           ^~~~
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:96203:50: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
96203 |           case 4:  zPayload[3] = (u8)(v&0xff); v >>= 8;
      |                                                ~~^~~~~
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:96204:11: note: here
96204 |           case 3:  zPayload[2] = (u8)(v&0xff); v >>= 8;
      |           ^~~~
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:96204:50: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
96204 |           case 3:  zPayload[2] = (u8)(v&0xff); v >>= 8;
      |                                                ~~^~~~~
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:96205:11: note: here
96205 |           case 2:  zPayload[1] = (u8)(v&0xff); v >>= 8;
      |           ^~~~
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:96205:50: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
96205 |           case 2:  zPayload[1] = (u8)(v&0xff); v >>= 8;
      |                                                ~~^~~~~
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:96206:11: note: here
96206 |           case 1:  zPayload[0] = (u8)(v&0xff);
      |           ^~~~
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c: In function ‘jsonTranslateTextToBlob’:
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:205078:7: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
205078 |     if( strncmp(z+i,"null",4)==0 && !sqlite3Isalnum(z[i+4]) ){
       |       ^
/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c:205084:3: note: here
205084 |   default: {
       |   ^~~~~~~
[100%] Built target SQLite3
```

So basically, according to the output, the object file should now be present in my build directory, but it isn't, I checked using my file explorer as well. I even tried using some generated code to do this for me, but I get exactly the same results as above.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Is the file here? `CMakeFiles/SQLite3.dir/home/rikus/Documents/git_projects/CPP-Project/libraries/sqlite/core/source/sqlite3.c.o`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes there is such a file there, I assume this is the object file I am looking for, thanks for the help. 

Could you perhaps further clarify why it ended up there instead of in my build directory?

Comment: I don't know why it ended up there, but that path is in the first line of output shown.

Comment: Seems like it put the object file in the same directory as the source. "*when I go to look in my directory*" 1) What directory are you looking in? 2) What directory is your cmake file in? 3) What directory did you run cmake from?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`add_library` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html)...

> By default the library file will be created in the build tree directory corresponding to the source tree directory in which the command was invoked.

You didn't specify a build directory in your makefile, and presumably not when you invoked cmake, so it built in the source directory.

If you want to build elsewhere, search for "out of source build".